# Program installed for one user cannot be accessed from other user even full path is provided

Tags: linux, node.js, monit, npm, pm2

I have all the npm pacakages installed for a particular user (i.e) not root (/home/otheruser/*)

I am using monit to see whether to check the program is running. In this case its pm2, which is in

```
/home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2
```

I cannot use pm2 even when I tried using the full path from other users in the terminal even with root user. It didnot gave any output or nothing happened there like below.

```
root@server:~$ /home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2 list
```

whenever I run node modules with different users like

```
root@server:~$ /home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/forever -v
root@server:~$ /home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/db-migrate -v
root@server:~$ /home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2 -v
```

And I get the below in the syslog

```
node[5791]: No AX.25 port data configured
node[5791]: No AX.25 port data configured
node[5791]: No AX.25 port data configured
```

How to get that working from other users

Answer (score 0):

**nvm** is not a real program. It's a bash function that gets loaded in the user's .profile, .bashrc, or ... so sudo doesn't automatically pick it up from the $PATH like most other programs.

You can create a symbolic link and then try to access it

> sudo ln -s "/home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/pm2"        "/usr/local/bin"

Comment: No this doesnt help. If I installed pm2 as a other user, it stores .pm2 records in /home/otheruser/.pm2, the problem is from root or some user, i cannot even run the pm2 by providing full path

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the below in the environment variable of the logged user(root) in which you are trying to run pm2 command and then it will works

> NVM_DIR="/home/otheruser/.nvm"
> NVM_BIN="/home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/bin"
> PATH="/home/otheruser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin"